# sending files to server and receiving feedback

Tags: objective-c

I have this code who send a file to my server:

```
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=thefile&&filename=recording"];
    [urlString appendFormat:@"%@", data];
    NSData *postData = [urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                               allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSString *baseurl = @"http://websitetester.com/here.php";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseurl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [urlRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    [connection start];

    NSLog(@"File Send to server!");
```

this code works perfectly but I would like to receive a return from the server, the php file at the end of the code I show:

```
<?php

if(...){

...

echo "Data Received";

}else{

...

echo "Error in server";
}

?>
```

All I'm trying is receive this echo in php and show an alert inside my app, how code I can implement inside my code to do that?

```
EDIT
```

Hey I find a code who receive the return data in objetive-c, the code is:

```
NSURLResponse* response;
    NSError* error;


    NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"return: %@",returnString);
```

and now the code works the way I expected.